# How to return Array from Firebase Snapshot

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I'm trying to retrieve some Data from Firebase (which works perfectly), but my colleague needs that I return the value of a snapshot as an Array, so that he can use it in another file. 
And as far as I know, it's impossible knowing that the value event is **Asynchronous**.

here's an example:

```
function getData() {
let current = [];
qRef.on("value", function (snapshot) { //qRef is the reference to my DB
    current = snapshot.val();
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
return current; //expected value is the returned data from the snapshot
}
```

Is there any alternative solution?
Thanks.

Comment: Inside the value event it returns the data as I want it.. 
But in the return statement I only have an empty array, which is normal because it's executed before the asynchronous event.

Comment: Return `snapshot.val()` in the value function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, you can't directly return the value because it's asynchronous.

Instead, you should make use of Promises:

```
function getData() {
  return qRef
    .once('value')
    .then(snapshot => snapshot.val())
    .then(value => [ value ])
}
```

Notice that I'm using `.once()` instead of `.on()`. `.on()` is for listening for changes, `.once()` is for just retrieving the value on-demand. Also, `.on()` doesn't use promises because a promise means "some async work will happen, then you'll get a result". Listening for a value might mean the callback is triggered many times.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!
I have just one issue, if I want to return an edited array of the snapshot, where can I add it?
(Because I actually need 10 shuffled values of the snapshot)

Comment: The function in the second `.then` is taking the value, and sticking it in an array. You can do any manipulation to the snapshot value you'd like in that function.

Comment: Hi, im new with firebase+ nodejs. Why when i console.log(getData()); Its return Promise { <pending> }. Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

if its not a snapshot , suppose a get function,then you can use this:-

```
function getData() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        let current = [];
        qRef.on("value", function (snapshot) { //qRef is the reference to my DB
            current = snapshot.val();
            resolve(current);
        }, function (errorObject) {
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            reject({
                error: true
            })
        });

    })
}
```

call it like

```
getData.then(function(current){
    desired_variable = current
})
```

since its a snapshot you can pass a callbak function and call it everytime.
callback function will set the data to the desired variable

```
 function getData(callback) {
    let current = [];
    qRef.on("value", function (snapshot) { //qRef is the reference to my DB
        current = snapshot.val();
        // write logic for current array
        callback(current);
    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        reject({
            error: true
        })
    });
}
```

it will be called like

```
getData(function(current){
       desired_variable = current;
})
```

hope it solves your issue

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.